# How increase the size of the legend in Gnulot

Tags: gnuplot

Can someone please direct me as how to increase the size of a legend in Gnuplot.

I wish to place the legend outside with:
`set key outside top`

But now I want the legend to appear larger in size. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font specification can follow the setting of key, from `help key`:

```
{font "<face>,<size>"}
```

You do not need to specify the face if you only want to change the size, e.g. to set font size to 16 do this:

```
echo 'set key outside top font ",16"; plot sin(x) w l' | gnuplot --persist
```

Which fonts are available depends on the terminal setting, e.g. if your terminal is wxt, you can find out more by running `help wxt`, etc.

Comment: `samplen`, `spacing`, `width` and `height` all make a difference as well I think ...

Comment: @Thor: I am using vim editor on an Ubuntu machine. Unfortunately, whenever I try setting the font: `set key outside top spacing 1.5 samplen 3 font ",16"`, I get the following error: `"test.gp", line 2: undefined variable: font`. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Hello_PG: Just tested your example and it works here `gnuplot 4.6 patchlevel 0`.

Comment: @Thor: Thanks a lot. I realized i was using an outdated version of gnuplot. The script worked fine once i upgraded to gnuplot 4.4.